# Dizer o nome após ter feito login

Tags: php

Boas, eu  estou  a fazer um sistema de login e queria que após eu ter feito login no meu site disse se bem vindo... mas não estou  a conseguir fazer isso. A única coisa que eu consigo fazer aparecer é bem vindo e o meu email.. ´

indexlogin.php:

```
//LOGIN
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxx", "xxxxxx") or die("Erro");                            // faz a conecxão a base de dados
$db = mysql_select_db("xxxxx",$connect) or die("Erro");                                         // selecionar a base de dados
if(isset($_POST["login"])) {                                                                        // vai verificar se existe
$email =($_POST ["email"]);                                                                     // md5 é a segurança basica. o email fica encrpitado ou se ja eu n vou  saber o email  dele
$password = md5($_POST["password"]);                                                                // o email e a pass são as variaveis
$verificar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'");      // verifica a coluna da base de dados
if (mysql_num_rows($verificar)<=0){                                                             // faz a contagem dos dados que recebeu.                                    
    echo "<h3> Dados de login incorretos!</h3>";                                                    // se não  econtrar os dados da erro
}else{
    setcookie("login",$email);
    header("Location: entrou.php");                                                                     // se econtrar os daods vai para o arquivo entrou.php
}
}
```

e o meu entrou.php:

```
    if(isset($_COOKIE["login"])) {      // apos confirmar os dados ao fazer o login corretramente ira dizer entra na conta.
    echo "BEM VINDO!";
    echo $_COOKIE["login"];
    }else{

    header("Location: ./");   // ./faz com  q vai para logo ao index.
    }
```

Comment: O nome seria o login? Se sim então tem que setar o cookie com o valor login setcookie("login",$_POST["login"]) caso contrario tem que retornar o nome na consulta e setar o cookie com esse valor retornado

Comment: Engraçado é que em nenhum momento o cara se atentou a criar uma variável `$login`... [facepalm]

Comment: como assim? desculpa é que eu faço programação a por volta d euns 3/4 meses

Comment: Aqui o erro era difícil achar porque não tem a pagina REGISTAR que está salvando o email  no banco assim   $email = md5($_POST ["email_registar"]);`  e na hora de verificar na pagina indexlogin.php você esta fazendo assim `$email =($_POST ["email"]);`. O correto é ` $email =md5($_POST ["email"]);` Editei aresposta

Answer (score 2):

> Aqui o erro era difícil achar porque não tem a pagina REGISTAR  que está salvando o email  no banco assim   `$email = md5($_POST ["email_registar"]);`  e na hora de verificar na pagina indexlogin.php você esta fazendo assim `$email =($_POST ["email"]);`. O correto é `$email =md5($_POST ["email"]);` Editei a resposta. A pagina REGISTAR eu vi em outra pergunta sua [**Login para admistradores e clientes**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/309241/login-para-admistradores-e-clientes)

Retorne o nome do usuário na declaração `SELECT`.

**indexlogin.php**

```
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxx", "xxxxxx") or die("Erro");                            
    // faz a conecxão a base de dados
    $db = mysql_select_db("xxxxx",$connect) or die("Erro");                                         
    // selecionar a base de dados
    if(isset($_POST["login"])) {  
                                                                         // 
    //vai verificar se existe
    /*********** aqui o seu erro *********/
    //$email =($_POST ["email"]); 

    /******* correto ************/ 
    $email =md5($_POST ["email"])


   // md5 é a segurança basica. o email fica encrpitado ou se ja eu n vou  saber o email  dele
    $password = md5($_POST["password"]);

    $verificar = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
    $res = mysql_query($verificar) or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
           $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

           // aqui está retornando o nome para setar o cookie com ele
           $nome = $row['nome'];

           setcookie("nome",$nome);
           header("Location: entrou.php"); 
        }else{
           echo "<h3> Dados de login incorretos!</h3>";
        }
    }
```

**entrou.php**

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["nome"])) {      // apos confirmar os dados ao fazer o login corretarmente ira dizer entra na conta.
echo "BEM VINDO!";
/***********************************
 pega o cookie com o nome do usuario
***********************************/
echo $_COOKIE["nome"];

}else{

header("Location: ./");   // ./faz com  q vai para logo ao index.
}
```

> OBS: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql/4675#4675)

Comment: como assim n funciona... Epá obrigado pela ajuda.. mas n está a funcionar.. agradeço na mesma :/

Comment: @LucasSintra, tem como mostrar o codigo que não está a funcionar?

Comment: n é n funcionar. É que continua a dizer bem vindo e depois o meu email. e eu queria que me disse o meu nome. eu ja tenho  o nome inserido na minha base de dados.

Comment: @LucasSintra, é porque você salvou o cookie com o email né. Veja na resposta, item 2 `Criar cookie com NOME do usuario` como deve ser feito, crie um cookie com o nome vindo do banco e depois recupere ele na entrou.php com `echo $_COOKIE["login"];`Independentemente desse comentário editei a resposta colocando mais detalhes.

Comment: olhe eu agradeço imenso a sua ajuda asério. Obrigado. mas deixe estar. até uma proxima!!

Comment: @LucasSintra, ainda não conseguiu? Qual o nome da coluna na tabela da base de dados que contém o nome ?

Comment: tenho  o banco  de dados que e a23144 e depois uma tabela para o sistema de login que é users. que tem o id,  nome, email, password, e a data.